# How to install new libraries in BQuant?

Tags: python, blpapi

I've been trying to connect BQuant to mySQL and want to try and import pymysql to do it. I was wondering if there was the ability to download new libraries not currently on Bquant because it seems like installing new libraries on my computer doesn't add them to it.

Comment: Enlighten us how you tried to install this... it might help other detect the issue at hand. Also... share your tracebacks with us by updating your question. Error code starts with > to get the yellow box. Inside the yellow box you can use tripple ` followed by the word python and then your code, closure of the code with trippe`.